# How to find the sum of the minor diagonal in a matrix (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to find the sum of the minor diagonal in a matrix, but my code only shows the first number in the matrix. Is there any way to fix it?

```
//sum of minor diagonal in matrix
public static int minorDiagonal(int[][] array){
    int k = 0, j = 0;
    int sumMinD = 0;
     k = array.length - 1;
    for ( j = 0, k = 0; j <= array.length && k >= 0; j++, k--) {
            sumMinD += array[j][k];

    }
return sumMinD;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minor diagonal of a matrix, like the major diagonal, runs across the center diagonal.  But the minor diagonal runs from the upper right to the lower left.  Assuming you had a 4x4 matrix, you want to sum the following four points:

```
(0, 3)
(1, 2)
(2, 1)
(3, 0)
```

Translating this into a loop gives us the following:

```
int sumMinD = 0;
int k = Math.min(array.length, array[0].length);
for (int i=0; i < k; ++i) {
    sumMinD += array[i][k - 1 - i];
}
```

I use `Math.min` to find the *smaller* of the row or column length when figuring out how long the minor diagonal is.  This covers the edge case of a rectangular matrix where the height and width may not be equal.

### Demo

Comment: This code works but only when the rows are equal to or less than the columns. I tried running it with a 3x2 and it gave me an out of bounds exception.

Comment: @JasmineGomezFerrer I updated my answer to cover non square matrices.  Take a look at the demo.

Answer (score 1):

Consider you had following matrix:

1 2 **5**

4 **1** 3

**0** 9 4

Minor diagonal consists of 0 + 1 + 5 = 6

The elements of minor diagonal are at positions: **[2][0]**, **[1][1]** and **[0][2]**

Your code is:

```
for ( j = 0, k = 0; j <= array.length && k >= 0; j++, k--) {
        sumMinD += array[j][k];
}
```

Your **k** is initialized to zero and you keep decreasing it, you will get **ArrayIndexOutOfBounds** exception, change your **j** to **yourMatrix.length-1** make **j** decrease on every iteration **j--** and **k** increase **k++**, and you should have it fixed.

Your final working loop would be:

```
for ( j = array.length-1, k = 0; j >= 0; j--, k++) {
        sumMinD += array[j][k];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why did you set k as 0 in this line?

```
for ( j = 0, k = 0; j <= array.length && k >= 0; j++, k--)
```

It will run for loop once because k will be -1 after first time. So

> k >=0

will be false.

I think you have to remove k=0 part.